# Problem in installing nvidia-docker in windows 10 system

Tags: docker, windows-10, nvidia-docker

I just started learning about docker so this question might be trivial for some of you. 
I installed the latest version of docker which is 19.03.2 in my windows 10 Enterprise(64 bit) and switched on the Linux Containers. My guide suggested me to use docker for my deep learning project(PyTorch framework based). I read several articles telling about as to why using docker makes life easy and I could follow most of them. For me, the main reason for using docker was due to the unavailability of GPU resource. So I successfully installed the docker 19.03.2 in my windows system. But for using GPU support from NVIDIA I had to install nvidia-docker.

This is when I got confused. There are few places which explain installing procedure for Linux environment but I could not find any for a windows system. Also few says that in the future, nvidia-docker2 packages will no longer be supported. So I am very confused at this point.

Some of my friends suggested me to use google colab instead of docker. I agree with them it's very useful but what if I still want to use docker only.  I believe there must be some solution.

Any help and suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to the above question.
The answer is simple and clear. nvidia-docker is not available for windows.

You guys can check here [Is Microsoft Windows supported?](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions):

> Is Microsoft Windows supported?
>
> No, we do not support Microsoft Windows (regardless of the version), however you can use the native Microsoft Windows Docker client to deploy your containers remotely (refer to the [dockerd documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#description)).
>
> -- https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#user-content-is-macos-supported

Thanks

Comment: Can you please link and quote a source? It will make the answer more usable for future visitors.

Comment: Yes sure. Give me some time.

Comment: Nice. I added the quote.

Comment: wait @SauravRai, i use win10 + vscode + docker desktop - i need to create docker image of a flask app, my app needs nvidia support - this will not work?

Answer (score 1):

nvidia-docker is now available for Windows WSL2, please check https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html but you have to be a member in Windows Insider Program. Depending on private testing, at this moment performance on CUDA applications on native Linux is much better than WSL2, maybe we get performance improvements soon.

Comment: Cool. Can you give the link to the exact place or image for the benefit of others?